# Elasticsearch parent child has_child returns no results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to test out the parent/child relationship but havent throuble getting any results back for has_child queries. I have this mapping

```
PUT /thread-with-message-parent-child
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 24,
    "analysis": {
      ...
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "user_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "user_thread_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "unread": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "archived": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "message_content": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "icu_latin_index_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "icu_latin_search_analyzer"
        },
        "join_field": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "thread": "message"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a bunch of documents in, here is a specific example of a parent/child

Parent

```
GET /thread-with-message-parent-child/_doc/617108809?routing=1

{
  "_index" : "thread-with-message-parent-child",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "617108809",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 12930,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "_routing" : "1",
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "archived" : "50_false",
    "join_field" : {
      "name" : "thread"
    },
    "user_thread_id" : 2313845152,
    "user_id" : 50,
    "unread" : "50_false"
  }
}
```

And child

```
GET /thread-with-message-parent-child/_doc/617108809_125261438?routing=1
{
  "_index" : "thread-with-message-parent-child",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "617108809_125261438",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 12933,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "_routing" : "1",
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "user_id" : 50,
    "message_content" : "academic knight impressive weiss third airports moist turtle socialism khan vos regimen tweak reap survivor pres ats gabriel rocky heavy consequences mom indicates nostalgia altavista ",
    "join_filed" : {
      "name" : "message",
      "parent" : "617108809"
    },
    "user_thread_id" : 617108809
  }
}
```

However, none of my has_parent or has_child queries return anything.

```
GET /thread-with-message-parent-child/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "timeout": "3000ms",
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "message",
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you are indexing the child document, the name for the field for the `join` data type is written wrong. It should be `"join_field"` and not `"join_filed"`**

Update your child document as shown below

```
{
  "user_id": 50,
  "message_content": "academic knight impressive weiss third airports moist turtle socialism khan vos regimen tweak reap survivor pres ats gabriel rocky heavy consequences mom indicates nostalgia altavista ",
  "join_field": {
    "name": "message",
    "parent": "1"
  },
  "user_thread_id": 617108809
}
```

Now when you run the [`has_child`](http://elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) query, following search result will be there

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67234216",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_routing": "3",
        "_source": {
          "archived": "50_false",
          "join_field": {
            "name": "thread"
          },
          "user_thread_id": 2313845152,
          "user_id": 50,
          "unread": "50_false"
        }
      }
    ]
```